# How to make website with many template that active

Tags: theme-development, themes

I want to make a website with wordpress engine but with some features.

One website has 3 template and every template is active because I want to make 1 website that has 3 sub categories such us blog, portfolio, and photo gallery but with different templates and fitur in every sub-category.

Anyone knows how to do that, please ? Thank you very much in advance.

Comment: Show some research efforts please. Your question is very vague (what is an _active template?_) and overly broad.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes it is possible to create templates for different categories and tags for posts

you can also use a plugin like this http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/custom-post-background/

If you look at (for example) http://woothemes.com - then their free theme it already has a blog, portfolio and photo gallery templates for you.  This might help you to see what is possible with WordPress.